# Order by when using coalesce

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query where I need to order my results and am using COALESCE
Not sure how to perform this. MY sector table per code below has several columns eg: Health, Technology etc and I need to display this data in a specific order.

Unsure

```
     SELECT
        COALESCE(Sector.Sector,'') as "Asset Type",
        CAST (SUM (N.exposureFundPerNAV) *100 AS VARCHAR(20))
        END AS "Percentage"

FROM Nav AS N
INNER JOIN Fund ON N.fund = F.FC
```

Comment: You need `GROUP BY Sector.Sector` too.

Comment: You SELECT the a `Sector` table column, but that table isn't found in the FROM clause.

Comment: What is the specific order?

Comment: I need to order by sectors such as "Health", "Tech", "Media" etc. There are unions above and below the SQL in the above example

Answer (score 3):

you can use alias name in order by

```
 order by "Asset Type"
```

It seems to me you have not shared full query that's why i just point out only the order by clause in my answer